Нужна ли запятая после слова «запятую»?
«...твердил, что даже ставя запятую, необходимо «...сознавать, для чего ее ставите»

Нужна! Это деепричастный оборот.

@Серж, а вторая запятая после что нужна? Правило ведь есть.

Правильно:
...твердил, что даже ставя запятую, необходимо «...сознавать, для чего ее ставите».
Пояснение (почему нет первой запятой после союза что)

Деепричастный оборот должен обособляться по общим правилам, но при наличии частицы даже первая запятая не ставится.

Обособление оборота после подчинительного союза следует из правила Розенталя:


Пункт 2. Деепричастный оборот, стоящий после союза сочинительного или подчинительного либо союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой (такой оборот можно «оторвать» от союза и переставить в другое место предложения): Жизнь устроена так дьявольски, что, не умея ненавидеть, невозможно искренне любить (Ж. Г.);
Поэтому верно: ...твердил, что, ставя запятую, необходимо «...сознавать, для чего ее ставите».

Но при наличии частицы даже первой запятой нет: ...твердил, что даже ставя запятую, необходимо «...сознавать, для чего ее ставите».

Отсутствие запятой можно объяснить по аналогии с придаточным предложением, так как собственного правила для деепричастного оборота нет: ...твердил, что даже когда ставите запятую, необходимо «...сознавать, для чего ее ставите».
Розенталь, пункт 6. После выделительных частиц вот, ведь, стоящих перед подчинительным союзом в придаточной части, предшествующей главной, запятая не ставится: Хвастаться пока особо нечем, вот как работу выполним, тогда приезжайте.

Сравнить:

...вот когда работу выполним, тогда приезжайте. Правило.
...твердил, что даже когда ставите запятую, необходимо «...сознавать, для чего ее ставите». Придаточное предложение.
...твердил, что даже ставя запятую, необходимо «...сознавать, для чего ее ставите». Деепричастный оборот.

Впрочем, интересно было бы послушать другие решения задачи. Возможно, правило для деепричастного оборота при наличии
частиц все-таки существует.


Шарон, в правилах, действительно, ничего не говорится о частице даже. Но зато говорится о частицах только и лишь. Перед ними может ставится или не ставится запятая в зависимости от определенных условий.

Я бы тоже не стал ставить запятую.

@Серж Вообще говоря, у Розенталя п этой теме (стык двух союзов и частица) нет информации и для СПП. На стыке запятая не ставится, если у нас двойной союз, и это всё. А если нет двойного союза, но есть частица? Такого примера нет,  и пользователи решают вопрос сами. В Нацкорпусе в основном запятую не ставят, да и странно видеть такое предложение: "Внимательный собеседник заметит, что, даже когда Чеханков шутит, глаза его не смеются.   Лучше так:  "Двойная ирония заключалась в том, что даже когда Петров был очень мал, табличка выглядела нисколько не свежее нынешнего состояния".

https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CksqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCKAomCiQKA3JlcRIdChvRh9GC0L4g0LTQsNC20LUg0LrQvtCz0LTQsCAwAQ==

А в таком примере? Папа же, напротив, состояние противления рассматривает как непогрешительное, ибо «таковым (то есть сверхъестественным) он останется всегда и несмотря ни на что, даже когда люди неверны».

Здесь запятая из-за предлога.

@Серж Здесь придаточное является присоединительной конструкцией, а "даже" на правах присоединительного союза. значение – в том числе когда.
